# What is the meaning of this (potentially humorous) mathematical equation?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, popular-math

The equation in the image shown below (outlined in blue) was found on the cover of a magazine, along with several other "math equation jokes" like the "I heart pi" joke. My friends and I haven't been able to figure this one out, and I can't seem to identify the last part of the equation.

It's obvious that the first part (square root of negative one) is "I", and the heart symbol is self-explanatory. I suspect that "$mc^2$" corresponds to "e" (but perhaps this is intended to be purely phonetic, or maybe intended to mean "energy").

[image]

Comment: After looking over this extensively, I have concluded this is completely meaningless. Maybe this is the discovery of a whole new type of artistic mathematics?

Comment: @LoganMaingi That is a very good guess for a random guess.

Comment: @LoganMaingi It then becomes "I love MC Squareo," where MC Squareo is somebody like MC Hammer.

Comment: @LoganMaingi Ah! I think that might solve it! The magazine is from Edmund Optics, so "I ♥ E O" seems to be logical (and clever, I suppose). Gosh, now I feel like the message just ended up being "Be sure to drink your Ovaltine"...

Comment: Sure enough, look what I found on their website... http://www.edmundoptics.com/images/articles/example-equation.gif

Comment: @LoganMaingi Want to promote your comment to an answer? I think you earned a green checkmark for this one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- $\sqrt{-1}$ is referring to $i$, the [imaginary unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_unit). $i$ satisfies the equation $i^2 = -1$. This is sometimes written as $i = \sqrt{-1}$, though this is abuse of notation in some cases depending on your definition of $\sqrt{}$.
- ♥ is a [heart shape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_(symbol)), which is often interpreted as meaning or somehow being related to love.
- $E = mc^2$ is Einstein's formula for the [rest mass-energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence) of a massive body. $m$ is the rest mass (or invariant mass), and $c$ is the speed of light.
- $\frac1f=\frac1i+\frac1o$ is the [thin lens equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_lens_equation), which describes the distances of an object and the image of that object (which may be real or virutal) relative to a thin refractive lens in geometric optics. $f$ is the focal length of the lens which is defined by this formula in the limit $o \rightarrow \infty$.

So, this line could be read as (ignoring capitalization, punctuation, etc.) "I love eo". As the OP states, this image is taken from Edmund Optics, which I guess abbreviates their name as "eo". With that interpretation, it seems to be a promotional piece of some sort. [This image](http://www.edmundoptics.com/images/articles/example-equation.gif) on their website confirms that this is the intended interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Those number 1's are sloppy -- or is the bracketed amount on the right actually $-2$ instead of $-1$.  I will assume $-1$.

Then, the item in brackets can be rewritten as
$$
\frac{if}{f-i}
$$

But, I am not sure what this means.  Following from before, "I love [E]nergy if "over" f-i???